# PHP: How to render the view at the end?

Tags: php, controller

I'm trying to create my own little PHP-Framework just for fun and to learn.
But now I stuck with the View.

```
class Index extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->view->msg = 'This message is sended over the view.';
        $this->view->content = 'This is the INDEX-Content.';
        $this->view->render('index/index');
    }

    public function something() {
        // do something
        // and render it
        $this->view->content = 'This is the content from something.'
    }
```

So what I can do is to misuse the __destruct and render here my output. But I guess that is against the purpose of this method.

When I compare my intention with e.g. Zend Framework or Laravel they use e.g. an after() method to render a view.

But I do not understand which method can do this. The constructor is the first, the destructor the last and everything between it has to be called to work.
Are there any "magic" methods for this?

Comment: please stop confusing views with [templates](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should handle your HTTP I/O

- This is how you can [output](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/index.php#L117-L120)
- This is how a request is [executed](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Request.php#L934-987)
- This is how the action is [triggerd](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Controller.php#L66-90)

Sniff through the repo as much as you can, Kohana is a simple yet powerfull framework. (you can learn a thing or two)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your main Controller class :

```
public function __call($method,$arguments) {
    if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$arguments); //this is where the function is called
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

You can eliminate in hear constructors, destruct and other functions that you do not want to automatically render.

You can also have a variable in your main Controller class, autoRender set default to false and just set it to true when you want to produce a predefined output.

Also in the _call function, you can use the $method variable to have a predefined name for your view. Like for example lets say you would have a folder in your framework called Views and in there you would have a file called something.view_extension.

You can send to render like this : $this->render($method.'.view_extension');

Just a bulk idea you can work around. :)